How does Benzyl alcohol prevent BADGE (BPA + Epichlorohydrin) + IPD + Hexane-1,6-diamine from reacting?
I believe I understand how epoxy reactions work in general: The NH2 groups in the Hexane-1,6-diamine will react with the C2O triangles in the Bisphenol A diglycidyl ether to form longer polymer chains. However, the hardener of this specific 2 component epoxy resin contains:
   50% CAS 38294-64-3, which is BPA + Epichlorohydrin + IPD
   >=20% CAS 100-51-6, which is Benzyl alcohol, a common solvent
   <25% CAS 25620-58-0, which is the Hexane-1,6-diamine

My understanding is that CAS 38294-64-3 will turn into Bisphenol A diglycidyl ether ("BADGE") and then the Hexane-1,6-diamine would react with it. But apparently, that doesn't happen here because the stuff stays liquid for months. So how does the Benzyl alcohol prevent that NH2 + C2O reaction that would otherwise link the BPA ether into longer chains (and thereby make it harden)?
